# On the level of Newton's particle theory of light

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, quantum-electrodynamics, wave-particle-duality

Huygens and Maxwell have wave theories about light.

On the other hand Planck and Einstein have theories about particle nature of light and could explain blackbody radiation and photoelectric effect which theories of Huygens and Maxwell unable to explain.

What about Newton's particle theory of light? Does it have advantage of explaining a phenomenon that all wave theories unable to explain? Is Newton theory of light could be considered as root for "essential need" for particle imagination of light or it is merely a non-essential theory when we could have wave theories?

Comment: Quantum electrodynamics — the theory of the quantized electromagnetic field — supersedes all these theories, unifies the wave and particle natures of light, and is in superb accord with experiments. The older is-it-a-wave-or-is-it-a-particle theories are now mainly of historical or engineering interest. Why think about obsolete and inferior theories?

Comment: Furthermore only QED leads to the unification of electromagnetism with the weak nuclear force, something Newton, Huygens, Maxwell, Planck, and Einstein didn’t envision.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think we could not say we "understand" a theory until we could reproduce it ourselves and not only memorize it. and we couldn't reproduce QED without non-relativistic quantum mechanics. If it was simple, Heisenbrg would do it. and like this other steps backward are needed. so I think we should learn essentials of history. @Ghoster

Comment: Newton’s theory of light is certainly important in the history of physics. But I don’t see how it helps at all to get to QED. I do think that the Huygens/Maxwell wave theories and the Planck/Einstein particle theories lead to QED.

Comment: it is exactly my question. could we consider conflict between Newton and Huygens as a manifestation of wave-particle duality or it is only a childish theory from a great man and so is famous. (Mature theory is an essential one: that explains some experiments that the other one couldn't) @Ghoster

Comment: This might be more suited to the [History and Science and Mathematics SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Newton the main driving force (pardon the pun) for his particle theory of light was the use of his laws of motion to explain rectilinear propagation, reflection and refraction which the laws did well bar the "small" matters of the speeding up of light when it passes from air to glass (shown to be incorrect later) and diffraction (of Newton's era).
At the tome Newton was so well respected that it was difficult to accept any contrary opinions particularly as they came from "foreigners".  Nowadays it can sometimes be very difficult to imagine how much "nationalism" played a part in the acceptance of scientific theories.

The essential difference is that the properties of Newton's "corpuscles" are not the same as Planck's "photons" other than they are both imagined to be "particle" like.

Comment: On the contrary, nationalism in science is still somewhat rampant in a few huge countries. It is not a thing of the past, and the cases from the last time it happened, were the Nazi denouncing of ``Jewish Physics" and Soviets embracing Lysenkoism. i.e. it is not even a century away! We really have to thank Madame Émilie du Châtelet for unifying science in the European (and thus North American) context, otherwise it would likely still be rather nationalistic.

Comment: [Émilie du Châtelet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89milie_du_Ch%C3%A2telet) was quite someone at a time when women were in the main undervalued.

Answer (score 1):

One part of Newton's theory for light was that light of different colors corresponded to particles of different sizes. This was vindicated by Newton's double prism experiment, which showed that white light is in some sense a mixture of different colors. This outcome favored Newton over other contemporary theories (this was before Fourier analysis was known).

Another favor for Newton's theory is that it accounted for the model of ray optics and the rectilinear propagation of light (this was before Gaussian beams were known—granted light is not coherent in most real life circumstances but the point is that we now know waves can very well approximate a ray).

One difficulty of Newton's theory of light was the challenge of explaining diffraction of light, which was known at the time (see [this post](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/12691/when-was-single-slit-diffraction-first-observed)). How is it able to bend around corners of a thin slit? He did provide ideas at the time for how this is possible, but it was unclear if it was convincing to others.

Another question is related to refraction. Newton predicted that light would travel faster in a denser medium like water (compared to light in air or a vacuum), and Huygens (using his wave theory of light) predicted that light would travel slower in a denser medium. However, I think the measurement of the speed of light in water wasn't done until the 1850's by Léon Foucault, so this was not an issue to Newton at the time.

Comment: Is there any among this favours of Newton theory that Huygens couldn't explain with his theory? @Maxi